# Thermostat & transformer

Tags: thermostat

I want to ensure I'm safe.

Is it normal to find fluctuating 12 volts when the thermostat (2-wire heat-only) is at "rest" and not calling for heat? The thermostat appears to function normally with a zone valve opening and an end switch making when a call goes out for heat.

The reason for the question is a "hot" transformer smell, similar to the old Lionel train sets as an example, that I don't recall noticing before. The thermostat was disconnected while replacing the zone valve and doing some plumbing work.

When calling for heat I'm getting 24-volt readings which is what I expect. When not calling for heat I get a 24-volt reading at the transformer and would expect 0-volt readings further "downstream" since the thermostat is open but instead I'm getting 12-volt readings.

1. Is that normal?
2. Is that a possible reason the transformer smells "hotter" than I remember?
3. Is the transformer just going bad?

Comment: "12 volt current" will have a lot of people burrying their heads under a pillow, whilst dribbling profusely. Do you have a diagram of the setup that we can see? 24V DC? As a blind guess, it should be 0V if the thermostat is closed, 24V indicates open. 12V suggests a wiring problem. But without a diagram we're guessing. Possibly better in DIY se as there doesn't seem to be a project here. If it seems to be getting hot and smelling it may be a good idea to throw the switch, turn it off and get someone in to look at it.

Comment: Lets not close this so fast. OP could get some sense of action to take, etc.

Comment: you failed to include a very important piece of information, all available info about the transformer. ... it is not possible to help you if we have to guess about the transformer output

Comment: Your thermostat probably has a "heat anticipator". I should be set to match the zone valve current. The anticipator being a wire wound resistor will have a voltage drop when the thermostat connection is closed, adding a small amount of heat to the temperature sensing apparatus. I hope this helps.

Comment: Not nearly enough information for us to troubleshoot.  Need a rough wiring diagram of the 24V-side system, photos if possible, also need to know the point you are measuring and whether you are on AC or DC on the meter.

Comment: Is your transformer 24VAC if so is your transformer grounded? If one leg of it is not grounded then you will get fluctuating voltages to ground. If it is not grounded verify with the manufacturer that it should be grounded.

Comment: If the transformer is center tapped from 1 side to the middle will read 12 volts , outside to outside 24v, if you touch the transformer is it two hot to hold? If two hot the load is larger than it can supply or some windings may be shorting usually caused from an overload that heated the windings enough to break down the varnish (winding insulation).